# Remove from collection where exists in another collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Let's say I have 2 collections which both have a `phone` attribute:

```
$contacts = Contact::all();
$optouts = Optout::all();
```

I want to update the `$contacts` collection and remove all which are opted out. So I want to remove all `$contacts` whose `phone` is present in `$optouts`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$contacts = Contact::all();
$optouts = Optout::all()->pluck('phone');

$filtered = $contacts->whereNotIn('phone', $optouts);
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Answer (score 1):

one option would be:

```
$phones = $optouts->pluck('phone')->toArray();

$newContacts = $contacts->reject(function ($contact) use ($phones) {
    return in_array($contact->phone, $phones);
});
```